# SSRS - show field in expression based on where clause?

Tags: reporting-services, dax, ssrs-2012

I have a data table that looks like the below. This shows the top 3 subcallcategories based on the amount of calls. The "order" column is a row number that shows which order the subcallcategory was in based on the calls.

I am trying to write some DAX in SSRS which displays the following

> Anxiety was the most common counselling call, followed by Work Related
> Stress and Bereavement

I have written the below code however it doesn't seem to be picking up the last 2 categories? Anyone have any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
=IIf(Fields!Order.Value = "1" and Fields!Category.Value = "Counselling", Fields!SubCallCategory.Value, "") & 
    " was the most common counselling call, followed by " & 
    IIf(Fields!Order.Value = "2" and Fields!Category.Value = "Counselling", Fields!SubCallCategory.Value, "") & 
    " and " & IIf(Fields!Order.Value = "3" and Fields!Category.Value = "Counselling", Fields!SubCallCategory.Value, "")
```

[image]

Below is my current output

[image]

Comment: I assume this is no actually DAX but just an SSRS expression? Is the data in your sample stored in SQL Server relational database or does it come from a SSAS/OLAP cube? If it comes from a normal relational database it might be easier to do this work there. The reason the current expression does not work it that `Fields!Order.Value` can only be 1 value at a time, what you have done is like write in query that reads `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE OrderID =1 and OrderID =2` which will never return results.

Answer (score 0):

As Alan mentioned, your expression is just looking at a single row of data.

You would need to put this expression in a table with Grouping by Category.

Then you would look for the ones in your ORDER and use that Sub Cat value. I use MAX and NULL to get matching values like

```
=MAX(IIf(Fields!Order.Value = 1, Fields!SubCallCategory.Value, NOTHING)) & 
    " was the most common " & Fields!Category.Value & " call, followed by " & 
    MAX(IIf(Fields!Order.Value = 2, Fields!SubCallCategory.Value, NOTHING)) & 
    " and " & MAX(IIf(Fields!Order.Value = 3, Fields!SubCallCategory.Value, NOTHING))
```

The MAX will get the SubCat value over NOTHING (SSRS for NULL) for the ones in the right ORDER.

This would give one line for Counselling and one for Legal.

You could also add the totals in with

```
MAX(IIf(Fields!Order.Value = 1, Fields!Calls.Value, 0))
```

I assume your ORDER field is an INTEGER and doesn't need the quotes.